# SELECT records on distinct dates SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, grouping, having

I want to obtain all users who have 3 or more records in the DB however they cannot have the same date. Example table:

```
User1 40 12/11/15
User1 33 13/11/16
User1 23 04/09/16
User2 21 30/09/16
User3 12 12/11/16
User3 54 12/11/16
User3 99 04/09/16
```

So from here, I want to obtain User1 only, User3 has 3 records, but since 2 of them are on the same day, he doesn't qualify. (**it is okay if two or more records are on the same day, as long as there are at least 3 on distinct dates, so if we add one more record for user3 on a different date, he would also satisfy the requirements.**)

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT id, price, date
FROM Table
WHERE id
IN (

SELECT id
FROM Table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT( ocust ) >=3
)
```

It takes care of the requirement to have 3 or more records, however I don't know how to take care of the distinct date requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `DISTINCT` to the `COUNT`, and change `ocust` (whatever that is) to `date`:

```
SELECT id, price, date
FROM Table
WHERE id
IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date ) >=3   -- Added DISTINCT, changed 'ocust' to 'date'
)
```